# How to make Iron-list selectable and navigatable with up and down key?

Tags: javascript, java, gwt, polymer, vaadin

Using the sample from [here](http://vaadin.github.io/gwt-polymer-elements/demo/#iron/IronListSample) from [Vaadin polymer elements](https://github.com/vaadin/gwt-polymer-elements):

Hier is my ui.xml:

```
    <i:IronList ui:field="list" as="item" addStyleNames="fit" selectionEnabled="true" multiSelection="false" indexAs="index">
        <template>
            <div>
                <div class="item" id="{{index}}" tabIndex="-1">
                    <img class="avatar" src="[[item.image]]"/>
                    <div class="pad">
                        <div class="primary">[[item.name]] [[item.index]]</div>
                        <div class="secondary">[[item.shortText]]</div>
                        <div class="secondary dim">[[item.longText]]</div>
                    </div>
                    <iron-icon icon="star"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </template>
    </i:IronList>
```

The iron-list items are not selectable. I tried:

```
@UiField 
IronList resultList;

Polymer.ready(resultList.getElement(), arg -> {

       resultList.setTabIndex(1);
       resultList.setSelectionEnabled(true);
       resultList.getPolymerElement().addEventListener(KeysPressedEvent.NAME, event -> {

        GWT.log("KeysPressedEvent!!");

      });
      return null;
});
```

The KeysPressedEvent event never fired and my iron-list items did never get the css `:focus` pseudo class. From the [Polymer Simple List Example](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-list?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=iron-list) I can see that a selected list item gets a css `:focus` pseudo class. In my case it did not happen.

From the polymer JavaScript [example](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-list). I should ass `tabindex$="[[tabIndex]]"` to the item but this does not work in GWT because I cannot ser a property ending with `$`.

I want to achieve the following:

1. The list's first element should receive tab focus when pressing the tab key from somewere else.
2. The list item which is selected should get the css class `:focus`.
3. I should be able to navigate the list items with up and down keys and select with enter key.

**How can I do that?**

Comment: Why focus I want to set the tabIndex.

Comment: I do not use the focus manually. I just want to get the same behavior as in this example: https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-list?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=iron-list

Comment: Seems to be the default behavior in the demo. The code doesn't do any keyboard event handling. Are you sure the list gets the focus? Does keyboard navigation work after you click on the list once?

Comment: I do not know if my list gets focus. No keyboard navigation does not work when I click on the list.

Comment: This is interesting https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-list/blob/master/demo/index.html#L152 .They set `tabindex$="[[tabIndex]]"` which seems to result in the selected item to have `tabindex="0"` while the other items have `-1`. This binding sets the `tabindex` attribute to the value of the `tabindex` property. The Vaadin demo doesn't do that.

Comment: Try to change your code accordingly. Change `tabIndex="-1"` to `tabindex$="[[tabIndex]]"` and remove `resultList.setTabIndex(1);`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I wrote that I use GWT and I cannot use ``tabindex$`` in GWT.

Comment: I don't know GWT. Why can't you use `tabindex$`? `[[]]` and `{{}}` seem to work fine. The `$` here is not related to the shortcut for `querySelector` that can be used in JS code. It indicates attibute binding instead of property binding.

Comment: If you do not know GWT you should not write in this question!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by this. I know Polymer quite well and if you provide enough information about GWT it shouldn't be too hard to solve the riddle.

Comment: I think it is hard to explain when you do not know the internal GWT system.

Comment: I think you just need to figure out how to do Polymer attribute binding from GWT. That's what `tabindex$=...` does. The model provided to each item provides a `tabIndex` property which needs to be bound to the `tabindex` attribute.

Comment: Do you think it will not work without it?

Comment: There is always a way, but I have no idea. Can't imagine this be so hard. What's the problem with `$` in GWT? Can't you escape it somehow so GWT ignores it?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer You may know the answer from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35372170/handle-keyboard-events-for-iron-list